# How to programmatically accept permissions on Xiomi and Huawei phones

Tags: android, testing, permissions, automated-tests

I want to assign all the permissions to the application during installation.
I know if I install the app using

```
adb install -g <apk_name>
```

but this works for API 23 and above.

My issue is all the `Xiomi and Huawei phones` which are `below API 23` , they also show a popup when you try to access camera, record audio, etc. Those are system popups.

Now if the phone is on API 23 and above I know I can use `requestPermissions()` but how can I programmatically accept the permissions from these kind of popups .

> Note - This is required for my automation testing.

Comment: If nothing else, you may be able to use `UiAutomator` to automate accepting the permission in the dialog, as part of the tests themselves.

Comment: It is not necessary that permission popup will appear at a particular place. One cannot add test for the unknown location.

Comment: `UiAutomator` works on widgets with IDs and/or captions, not pixel coordinates.

Comment: @CommonsWare By location I didn't meant screen pixels. What I meant  was that the popups may appear at different places. Also, one doesn't know about the id of the native popup . Well about the captions they are different on different devices.

Comment: "Also, one doesn't know about the id of the native popup" -- that is what `uiautomatorviewer` is for. "Well about the captions they are different on different devices" -- and your code can use `Build` values, like `MANUFACTURER` and `PRODUCT`, to identify that you are running on such devices and routing to the particular code to deal with the dialogs. This is not ideal. However, I will be rather surprised if you find a solution akin to `adb install -g`, which is why I am pointing out this approach.